# Fill full screen design with twitter bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

i am trying to make the screen to fully fill with the design no empty things around and also be responsive i have tried it so far.

Also want to Size of text-box and Login button.

[**`Demo fiddle`**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/jkJXB/)

[**Result Screen**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/jkJXB/embedded/result/)

Current Output

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following TWB 2 syntax :

replace

```
<div class="container">
```

by

```
<div class="container-fluid">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/smefhyyr/

Answer (score 6):

Add `-fluid` to your `container` class:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
</div>
```

Even then, Bootstrap adds `20px` padding either side of the document, which of course - you can remove like below:

```
<style type="text/css">
   #full-width {
       padding: 0;
   } 
</style>

<div id="full-width" class="container-fluid">
</div>
```

**Example Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/qFKdF/1/

Answer (score 2):

hope it will help you, u need to add custom div with  `width:100%`

```
.container-full {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 100%;
}
```

[**demo**](http://bootply.com/72278)

Answer (score 0):

A shameless plug but I just released an open source project to exactly this issue. It plays nicely with bootstrap but gives you the look you are going for with only a few lines of code:

https://github.com/rknell/snappyapps-layout

```
<div class="sa-container">
    <div class="sa-layout horiztonal">
        <div>Sidebar (obviously you will need to style this with colours etc)</div>
        <div class="grow">Content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```